# .OnClickListener versus .OnChildClickListener

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I know that `(View.)OnClickListener` is called whenever a view has been clicked on.

What I don't understand properly is, what `OnChildClickListener` does. I also wanted to know the difference between them.

P.S. I have read Android's documentation on `OnChildClickListener` but I am not able to grasp the concept.

Comment: OnChildClickListener is available on ExpandableListView only. If you expand a list item, it has children list items under it, so that's what this interface is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on Tenfour04's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65816345/onclicklistener-versus-onchildclicklistener#comment116368332_65816345), `OnChildClickListener` is actually [`ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener), which is part of [`ExpandableListView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView).  It's used with [`ExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView#setOnChildClickListener(android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener)) to listen to clicks on the children of groups in the expandable list view.  For the groups themselves, there's [`ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener).  These are attached to the parent `ExpandableListView` in place of putting an `OnClickListener` on each individual item.

[`View.OnClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener) is, as you note, for listening to clicks on any `View`.